# uniqueness of solution and continuity for differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-pde

> What is disturbing me is how is it possible that if the solution of a differential solution is unique then, it's continuous ? Do you have
>   any idea how, this, is possible ?  Apparently, it has some connection
>   with Volterra integral and functional equations.

I have that stochastic differential equation (or perhaps it isn't one ... I'll explain further why I don't really know):

$$ \psi(t) = \int^t_0 K(t-s) [ C \psi^2(s) - \lambda \psi(s) - \theta^2 ] ds $$

- with $K$ a kernel ( I don't really know what it exactly means, apart
  from wikipedia's definition. If you need any additional information
  on $K$ let me know please),
- $C$ a constant

since I'm dabbling with SDE, and that question is about one step in solving a SDE, perhaps this isn't a SDE. Apparently, the solution $ \psi $ of that problem is unique and continuous in $ L_{loc}^2 ( \mathbb R_+, \mathbb R ) $.

Thank you very much for anyone considering to answer me. I am very sorry if my question is not of the best accuracy. If you're lacking just a few bits, let me know and I'll try my best to give those infos.

Comment: It isn't really clear what you're asking. What you've written is an *integral equation,* not a differential equation.

Comment: @Math1000 I don't know what an integral equation, it sounded good, do you have any idea how I could be more precise in the question?

Comment: An integral equation is just that - an equation for a function in terms of the integral of a function. Just like how a differential equation is an an equation for a function in terms of the derivative of that function. There may in fact be an equivalent differential equation here; I don't know. But as written, you are asking about an integral equation, not a differential equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of a differential equation is, by definition, continuously differentiable. It may not exist, and even if it does exist, there may be branching points where one initial condition leads to different solutions.

The equivalent differential equation is $ψ''=K(Cψ^2 −λψ −θ^2)$ with initial conditions $ψ(0)=ψ'(0)=0$. The right side is polynomial, thus any solution is analytical and unique. Due to the quadratic term, the solution may exist only for a finite time. One can multiply by $2ψ'$ and integrate to find that
$$
ψ'^2=K\left(\frac23ψ^3−λψ^2 −2θ^2ψ\right) +C\implies C=0
$$
and conclude that the solution is bounded inside some interval $[-a,0]$ and thus exists for all times and oscillates.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. Do you mind elaborate why the equation you gave is the one equivalente? I m surprised by the fact you put a second order derivative on the LHS. Also, you are saying that the solution is also continuous, so it has nothing to do with unicity? Finally, is it important here that we involve kernel, or can I consider that as a classic differential equation?

Comment: Because by partially integrating twice you get $y''(t)=y(0)+y'(0)t+\int_0^t(t-s)y''(s)\,ds$. Now compare with your ODE.

Comment: excuse me, I tried to understand your reasoning but perhaps you misunderstood me ? $$K(t-s)$$ isn't the product of a constant times $t-s$ but it is a function. Does that change something ? Or did I misunderstood you ? Because I don't see a $t-s$ in my equation that should appear given what you have written in your comment. Your solution still solves my original problem, but I'm trying to understand the equivalence form you've written.

Comment: In that case you are right, the question becomes more complicated, you need to treat the integral equation directly as fixed-point equation,  complicated by the non-linear square. One would probably need some variation of variational calculus to find the relevant fixed-point theorems.